# What's the return type and argument of putchar()

Tags: c, parameters, arguments, return-type, putchar

I see that return type of putchar() is int,

> int putchar(int char)

but

```
for(i=65;i<91;i++)
putchar(i);
```

gives output ABC...... How?Shouldn't it return int?

Plus, it turns out that I can use character in argument too.How?

Comment: You're not using the return value.

Comment: "return value" is not the same as what's printed.

Answer (score 2):

You're not printing the return value. To print the return value, assign the result to another variable, and print that.

```
for (i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
    int ret = putchar(i);
    printf("\nputchar return value = %d\n", ret);
}
```

The output of this will be:

```
A
putchar return value = 65
B
putchar return value = 66
```

and so on up to `Z` and `90`.

`65` is the ASCII character code for the letter `A`. `putchar()` sends the character code to the terminal, which displays the corresponding character.